# asmx web service in IIS: Any way to attach to process and get live feedback?

Tags: web-services, iis, asmx

I am wondering if there is a tool that can be used to attached to the a single threaded asmx service call hosted in IIS, and return feedback based on the current actions the service is taking.

I know I can setup tracing, and then monitor the trace, but I am looking for a more dynamic way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own performance counters.